# Universal Apps(WinRT) -How to fire event of MediaElement when the app is suspended

Tags: audio, windows-runtime, win-universal-app, mediaelement, background-task

I am developing a music player and use a MediaElement control, but its events as MediaOpened or MediaEneded don't fire when the app is suspended(when the app window is minimized). How can I fire event under the suspended condition?

All I want to do is automatically play the next track when the previous track ends even if the app is not foreground.

Comment: Which OS / version? (8.x, Phone or Desktop? or 10?)

Comment: For Windows 10 Universal App. An official sample gives me some hints, and I try to do it, but the sample is a little difficult for me. [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/backgroundaudio)

Comment: Yes, it is complex than just doing audio in the foreground due to the memory constraints on low-end hardware. Can you get the sample to work?

Comment: I tried hard these days, and I succeeded to play background audio! 1. Use MediaPlaybackList Class for MediaElement source 2. Use SystemMediaTransportControls Class(IMPORTANT: IsPlayEnabled and IsPauseEnabled properties muse be set to true) 3. Set AudioCategory property of MediaElement to BackgroundCapableMedia 4. Add BackgroundTask(audio), these 4 steps made background audio playing possible. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: @NaotoIshida : could you post the sample as the sample given by msdn has bugs and keeps on crashing.